# Up and Running a project packaged through 'setuptools' in a venv with all requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

The project structure is something like below:

```
project/
|-- src/
|   |--sub_project1/
|      |--__init__.py
|      |-- main.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- requirements.txt
|
|-- setup.py
|-- README.md
|-- MANIFEST.in
```

I started with `setuptools` in order to package my project. I think I am successful in creating a distribution but I am not sure with the later process of how to thoroughly set up the project in the virtual environment (`venv`) to run `src\sub_project1\main.py`.

Steps I followed so far:

- Created `requirements.txt` through `pipreqs`.
- Created `setup.py`, which sets `include_package_data=True` to include `requirements.txt` mentioned in `MANIFEST.in`

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import pkg_resources

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

# read data from .txt as str, decode and then split to get a list of requirements
requirements = pkg_resources.resource_string('src', 'requirements.txt').decode("utf-8").split()

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=requirements,
    ...
)
```

`MANIFEST.in`:

```
include *.txt
```

- Generated the distribution:

  `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

Now, since I have packaged the project, I want to create a Virtual environment, set up dependencies and run it.

I started by creating a virtual environment, using `python -m venv <DIR>`. And have one of the below two commands to install all requirements:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or

```
pip install ./downloads/SomeProject-1.0.4.tar.gz
```

which does install all the required packages. But, from here onwards I am not sure about to steps to actually execute my script. How to actually execute the project in the created virtual environment?

Moreover, some questions I have:

1. Is `setup.py` used only to install requirements? How are the above two commands different in terms of output?
2. Apart from installing requirements, do you manually need to put the project files in the needed directory? As pip install *.tar.gz didn't unzip any project files!
3. How to use `entry_points` in setup.py?

Comment: Can you give more details about your package? What script do you want to make executable, what package data do you want to include?

Comment: @NilsWerner, I have updated the post with project structure. I want to setup whole project in a `venv` and want the `src\sub_project1\main.py` as executable. I am including `src\requirements.txt` into package by using `include_package_data=True` and `MANIFEST.in`.

Answer (score 0):

To activate a virtualenv, you must run `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate`. Then, when you cd to the directory containing `setup.py` and run `pip install .`, it will install your package along with all of its dependencies.

At any point you can run `which pip` to see which pip an installation will use. If you want to install your package into the virtualenv, make sure this is `/path/to/venv/bin/pip`.

`pip install -r requirements.txt` will just install the packages listed in `requirements.txt`. `pip install /path/to/tar.gz` should work just like `pip install /path/to/package`.

Entry points is a bit more extensive but [here](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/) is a good resource for getting started with that.

Comment: So, firstly I manually need to have all the project files in the needed directory. Installing from a tar.gz won't get me the project files, right?

Comment: Do you need to edit the package files or just be able to install the package? If you need the files, you'll need to unzip the tar.gz to wherever you want to edit it, pip won't do that. However, as long as you install with the venv pip, and you have the venv active, you'll be able to use the package.

Comment: Yes, I just need package files to run the whole project. I used `pip install .` which installed the package, and used entry_points to run the main script. It does so, but when it runs it's unable to found the other dependent modules in the same directory as main.

Comment: Though I am in the `project` directory and it has all the files. Moreover, I also tried `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` which created a build directory with all files. I am not sure how to use to the Build Distribution!

Comment: Let's continue this [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173565/room-for-moxieball-and-deepaksurana)

Answer (score -3):

You can check out https://setupy.info/ for more informations about setup.py, it should answer questions 1 and 2.

You could also use something like `pip install -e .` inside your project to install your package locally.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the link does explain the attributes for `setup.py` but still doesn't answer how the 2 commands I mentioned are different and how to get all project files from the distribution `.tar`